# Select right elements inside a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I explane as clear as possible my problem:
I have two vectors prova1 and prova2. Inside prova1 there is a collection of int numbers i.e.

```
prova1={0;1;2;4;6;7,8;9;10;11;12;13};
```

prova2 is a subset of prova1 i.e.

```
prova2={2;4;6;8;10;12;13};
```

my goal is to copy in a third vector (called "prova") only the sequences of elements inside prova2 that are inside prova1 and contigous.
For the vectors discribed above respect to the conditions I have two sequences:
{2;4;6} and {12;13}, in fact this two sequences have no separation elements inside prova1.

Here my code to approach this problem:

```
std::vector<int> prova1 = {0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
std::vector<int> prova2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13};
std::vector<int> prova;

for (int i=1;i<=prova1.size()-1;i++) {
    for (int j=1;j<=prova2.size()-1;j++) {
        if (prova2[j]==prova1[i]) {
            int variabile=prova2[j-1];
            if (prova1[i-1]==variabile) {
                prova.push_back(prova2[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but as you can see there is an issue:

can't include the first element of any sequences

please try give my some help to solve it.

Comment: Are the vectors sorted and/or only contain distinct numbers ?

Comment: @csgillespie sorry but I added this tag because stack suggested this tag

Comment: @Jarod42 yes they are sorted

Comment: Is there a limit of the sequence length? Is a sequence with 1 element a valid sequence?

Comment: @Flovdis no there is no limit to the lenght of vectors. A sequence of 1 elemnts is a kind of sequence, but this is not my case. I have sequences of sorted and different elements.

Comment: Have you tried [`std::set_intersection()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)?

Comment: @Manu343726 Set intersection is a possibility...but my problem is to copy the right contigous sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that's efficient and pretty simple to understand - as it runs through each element in `v1` it keeps track of whether it's not inside a running match, has only seen the first element of what might turn out to be a multi-element subsequence match, or is definitely inside such a match, and `push_back`s elements accordingly.

```
enum { unmatched, once, many } state = unmatched;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < v1.size() && j < v2.size(); ++i)
    if (v1[i] == v2[j])
        if (state == unmatched)
        {
            ++j;
            state = once;
        }
        else if (state == once)
        {
            v.push_back(v2[j - 1]);
            v.push_back(v2[j++]);
            state = many;
        }
        else
            v.push_back(v2[j++]);
    else
        state = unmatched;
```

See the full program running at [ideone.com here](http://ideone.com/hkCy0E), with output:

```
2
4
6
12
13
```

---

Update: here's how to include a sentinel to separate the subsequences:

```
const int sentinel = -1;  // or std::numeric_limit<int>::min or whatever else...

enum { unmatched, once, many } state = unmatched;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < v1.size() && j < v2.size(); ++i)
    if (v1[i] == v2[j])
        if (state == unmatched)
        {
            ++j;
            state = once;
        }
        else if (state == once)
        {
            v.push_back(sentinel);
            v.push_back(v2[j - 1]);
            v.push_back(v2[j++]);
            state = many;
        }
        else
            v.push_back(v2[j++]);
    else
        state = unmatched;
```

Then when you iterate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    if (v[i] == sentinel)
        std::cout << "starting new subsequence!\n";
    else
        std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
```

---

UPDATE: to capture the range of indices as requested in comments:

```
enum { unmatched, once, many } state = unmatched;
int j;
for (int i = j = 0; i < v1.size() && j < v2.size(); ++i)
    if (v1[i] == v2[j])
        if (state == unmatched)
        {
            ++j;
            state = once;
        }
        else if (state == once)
        {
            starts_at.push_back(j - 1);
            v.push_back(v2[j - 1]);
            v.push_back(v2[j++]);
            state = many;
        }
        else
            v.push_back(v2[j++]);
    else
    {
        if (state == many)
            finishes_at.push_back(j - 1);
        state = unmatched;
    }
if (state == many)
    finishes_at.push_back(j - 1);
```

Comment: I have an other question for you: Is possible to identify or isolate every sequence that the algoritm finds? In this case {2;4:6} and {12;13} are two distinct sequences and I want to apply on them some elaboration.

Comment: @CecchinoSMI yes, definitely - for example, if you have `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;`, then for `state == once` do `v.push_back(std::vector<int>());` to create an extra sequence container, then `v.back().push_back(v2[j - 1);` and similar for `v2[j++]` (for both `state`s).  You can then use two `for` loops to iterate over `v`.  A different, even simpler approach is to `push_back` a distinct sentinel value (any value you know your data won't have) in `state == once` *before* you push your sequence data, then you can use it later to know where the sequences start.

Comment: I want to use the second approach...in that case to identify the starting index of any sequence what I need to put inside the    push_back    function of the sentinel vector?

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: I've edited some code into my answer.  Honestly, if you struggle with this you should be thinking about taking some time out to learn C++ - it will be hard to get any real program working. :-/

Comment: Ok maybe my question above is not clear....i know that is possible to use a sentinel like your example, but in my case the sentinel needs to contain the right index in which a sequence is starting...this is my difficult :)

Comment: The vector v1 and v2 in my case are fixed, and very huge. I read these vector from a .txt file and it is impossible to add inside them sentinel values.

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: I'm not sure I understand yet.  What is the format in the text file?  How can you tell while reading that file where one vector ends and another starts?

Comment: yes you are right...but my real goal is to save the start index of any sequence inside a separate vector. You suggest me to add the value -1 before any sequence, but I don't want to add new values to the vector v.

Comment: The text file is a .txt tab delimited. I have 2 columns (my two vector).

Comment: @CecchinoSMI Well, that's very easy - just create `vector<size_t> starts_at;` and instead of `v.push_back(sentinel);` do `starts_at.push_back(j - 1);`.  Then `starts_at[` *n* `]` will tell you where subsequence number *n* starts in the `j` array.

Comment: Ok Tony D now is ok...to complete my algorithm I have the last request. What is the simpler way to know the end of my sequences?

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: if you do one final `starts_at.push_back(j.size());` after the `for`-loop that populates the vectors, then you can simply use `starts_at[` *n* `+ 1 ] - 1` to know the end of sequence *n*, but you will then need to make sure you only loop as in `for (int n = 0; n < starts_at.size() - 2; ++n) ...` (note the `-2`) if you use the `starts_at` vector as a way to iterate over the sub-sequences.

Comment: sorry Tony D but this last explanation is not clear....At the end of the for loop that populates the vectors, you suggest to implement a new for loop, where:

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: let me explain from scratch... say `starts_at` contains the indices in `j` where each subsequence starts, and that that data happens to be `[0, 3, 9, 12, 22]`, that data is already enough to tell us the *range* of indices for any subsequence: subsequence 0 is from 0 to 3-1, subsequence 2 is from 9 to 12-1, subsequence 4 is from 22 to `j.size()-1`; in other words, subsequence k is from `starts_at[k]` to either `starts_at[k+1]-1` *or* `j.size()-1`, and we can make that easier to use by just pushing `j.size()` onto `starts_at` so it's always `starts_at[k+1]-1`.  No extra `for` loop.

Comment: But in this way you are using the same variable "starts_at" to push_back the starts indexes and the end indexes...I'm worng?

Comment: And one other thing is that: I don't think that the end of any sequence is given by starts_at[k+1]-1. Because if you look at the vectors example, the end of subsequence {2;4;6} is not starts_at[2]-1.....

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: sorry - you're right - and I'd mentally been thinking we were splitting the input into subsequences and forgotten that we were also discarding some of the input... been too long since I first looked at this problem.  My suggestion won't work.  You will need to create a `finishes_at` `vector` too - I'll edit the code in the solution - one minute....

Comment: Ok...but in your code the last if seems to be outside the for loop...so the variable j is not recognize in finishes_at.push_back(j-1);

Comment: Tony the code doesn't work. As you cans see the finishes_at.push_back(j-1) fills the vector finishes_at with a lot of indexes...I aspect to find the same number of indexes of the vector starts_at

Comment: @CecchinoSMI - you're right again about j needing to be defined before the `for` loop, because the `finished_at.push_back(j - 1);` is after the foot loop (I had indented it too far making it look like it should have been inside, but now fixed)... keep that outside the `for` loop and you should have the same number of indices.  Also, do think about how this needs to work - I think you can work some of these things out yourself, especially when you clearly know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply using copy function(s) to copy ranges. You don't need to iterate vectors by yourself to do this. Have a look around std algorithms and play with it you can do it easily.

Comment: I know that there is the possibility to use the function copy...but I prefer to use something like the code above to semplify the copy of the right sequences

Answer (score 0):

I came to this simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> sequenceA = {0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
    std::vector<int> sequenceB = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13};
    std::vector<int> result;

    std::stable_sort(sequenceA.begin(), sequenceA.end());
    std::stable_sort(sequenceB.begin(), sequenceB.end());

    int indexA = 0;
    int indexB = 0;
    while (indexA < sequenceA.size() && indexB < sequenceB.size()) {
        const int valueA = sequenceA[indexA];
        const int valueB = sequenceB[indexB];
        if (valueA == valueB) {
            result.push_back(valueA);
            ++indexA;
            ++indexB;
        } else if (valueA < valueB) {
            ++indexA;
        } else {
            ++indexB;
        }
    }

    for (int value : result) {
        std::cout << value << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is this the result you need?

Comment: Give me some minutes to test this example

Comment: No...this example doesn't resolve my goal. Because in the output you can find the single elements like 8-10 that doesn't respect the condition "consecutive" inside sequenceA

Comment: You can see it running [here on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/GCOp9A) - the output is `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13,` - not quite the "{2;4;6} and {12;13}" subsequences mentioned in the program.

Comment: Sorry, but then you have to clarify your question. I look at the result as [2, 4, 6], [8], [10], [12, 13]. You told me sequences with 1 element are valid. So IMO this result is valid. Please provide some examples in your question and explain your goal in more detail.